# Heatmap in matplotlib with pcolor?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, heatmap

I'd like to make a heatmap like this (shown on [FlowingData](http://flowingdata.com/2010/01/21/how-to-make-a-heatmap-a-quick-and-easy-solution/)):
[image: heatmap]

The source data is [here](http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv), but random data and labels would be fine to use, i.e.

```
import numpy
column_labels = list('ABCD')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
data = numpy.random.rand(4,4)
```

Making the heatmap is easy enough in matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)
```

And I even found a [colormap](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) arguments that look about right: `heatmap = plt.pcolor(data, cmap=matplotlib.cm.Blues)`

But beyond that, I can't figure out how to display labels for the columns and rows and display the data in the proper orientation (origin at the top left instead of bottom left).

Attempts to manipulate `heatmap.axes` (e.g. `heatmap.axes.set_xticklabels = column_labels`) have all failed. What am I missing here?

Comment: There's a lot of overlap with [this heatmap question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975402/matplotlib-heat-map-set-white-color-some-field) - might be some good info for you there.

Comment: The label techniques from this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This is late, but here is my python implementation of the flowingdata NBA heatmap.

**updated:1/4/2014**: thanks everyone

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# <nbformat>3.0</nbformat>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Filename   : heatmap.py
# Date       : 2013-04-19
# Updated    : 2014-01-04
# Author     : @LotzJoe >> Joe Lotz
# Description: My attempt at reproducing the FlowingData graphic in Python
# Source     : http://flowingdata.com/2010/01/21/how-to-make-a-heatmap-a-quick-and-easy-solution/
#
# Other Links:
#     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from urllib2 import urlopen
import numpy as np
%pylab inline

page = urlopen("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv")
nba = pd.read_csv(page, index_col=0)

# Normalize data columns
nba_norm = (nba - nba.mean()) / (nba.max() - nba.min())

# Sort data according to Points, lowest to highest
# This was just a design choice made by Yau
# inplace=False (default) ->thanks SO user d1337
nba_sort = nba_norm.sort('PTS', ascending=True)

nba_sort['PTS'].head(10)

# Plot it out
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(nba_sort, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.8)

# Format
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 11)

# turn off the frame
ax.set_frame_on(False)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(nba_sort.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(nba_sort.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

# Set the labels

# label source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_statistics
labels = [
    'Games', 'Minutes', 'Points', 'Field goals made', 'Field goal attempts', 'Field goal percentage', 'Free throws made', 'Free throws attempts', 'Free throws percentage',
    'Three-pointers made', 'Three-point attempt', 'Three-point percentage', 'Offensive rebounds', 'Defensive rebounds', 'Total rebounds', 'Assists', 'Steals', 'Blocks', 'Turnover', 'Personal foul']

# note I could have used nba_sort.columns but made "labels" instead
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(nba_sort.index, minor=False)

# rotate the
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

ax.grid(False)

# Turn off all the ticks
ax = plt.gca()

for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    t.tick1On = False
    t.tick2On = False
for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    t.tick1On = False
    t.tick2On = False
```

The output looks like this:
[image: flowingdata-like nba heatmap]

There's an ipython notebook with all this code [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5427209). I've learned a lot from 'overflow so hopefully someone will find this useful.

Comment: The above code didn't run in iPythnon notebook. I had make some slight modification, changing nba_sort = nba_norm.sort('PTS',ascending=True, inplace=True) to nba_sort = nba_norm.copy()
nba_sort.sort('PTS',ascending=True, inplace=True) as the sort works by side-effect not by function return! Thanks for the wonderful conceret example!

Comment: Hmmm... you seems to be correct. Not sure what that is all about. I will correct the code. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the easiest way to make a graphic like this but display the value of the statistic in the table.  I.e. I want to make a `pcolor` like this but that has numerical values shown, too.  OR: I want to make a matplotlib `table` that colors its cells.  I've seen solutions to the other problem, and they're aesthetically ugly.  This looks great, if only I knew how to overlay the numbers.

Comment: Yeah.  I stumbled my way to that in answering someone else's question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21167108/2501018

Comment: @joelotz Would you be willing to contribute a (modified) version of this to the matplotlib docs?  If so, either just open a PR or ping me via email (see my profile).

Comment: Whenever I do a plt.savefig() the rotated x labels are trimmed in the saved figure ? How to get a figure exactly like one showed in the answer ? @joelotz

Answer (score 12):

The python seaborn module is based on matplotlib, and produces a very nice heatmap.

Below is an implementation with seaborn, designed for the ipython/jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
# import the data directly into a pandas dataframe
nba = pd.read_csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv", index_col='Name  ')
# remove index title
nba.index.name = ""
# normalize data columns
nba_norm = (nba - nba.mean()) / (nba.max() - nba.min())
# relabel columns
labels = ['Games', 'Minutes', 'Points', 'Field goals made', 'Field goal attempts', 'Field goal percentage', 'Free throws made', 
          'Free throws attempts', 'Free throws percentage','Three-pointers made', 'Three-point attempt', 'Three-point percentage', 
          'Offensive rebounds', 'Defensive rebounds', 'Total rebounds', 'Assists', 'Steals', 'Blocks', 'Turnover', 'Personal foul']
nba_norm.columns = labels
# set appropriate font and dpi
sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
sns.set_style({"savefig.dpi": 100})
# plot it out
ax = sns.heatmap(nba_norm, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, linewidths=.1)
# set the x-axis labels on the top
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
# rotate the x-axis labels
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
# get figure (usually obtained via "fig,ax=plt.subplots()" with matplotlib)
fig = ax.get_figure()
# specify dimensions and save
fig.set_size_inches(15, 20)
fig.savefig("nba.png")
```

The output looks like this:
[image: seaborn nba heatmap]
I used the matplotlib Blues color map, but personally find the default colors quite beautiful. I used matplotlib to rotate the x-axis labels, as I couldn't find the seaborn syntax. As noted by grexor, it was necessary to specify the dimensions (fig.set_size_inches) by trial and error, which I found a bit frustrating.

As noted by Paul H, you can easily add the values to heat maps (annot=True), but in this case I didn't think it improved the figure. Several code snippets were taken from the excellent answer by joelotz.

Answer (score 11):

Main issue is that you first need to set the location of your x and y ticks. Also, it helps to use the more object-oriented interface to matplotlib. Namely, interact with the `axes` object directly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
column_labels = list('ABCD')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell, notice "reverse" use of dimension
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)


ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul H, that works beautifully. I was using the `heatmap.axes` property, which for some reason doesn't do anything.

Comment: Do you know how to move the x-axis labels to be at the top? I tried the obvious `ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')` to no avail.

Comment: @JasonSundram You should open a new question for moving the label positioning, because, that should work and it is strange it does not.

Comment: @tcaswell, good point. New Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: @JasonSundram thanks for following up. That helps me a lot too!

Comment: @PaulH sorry to resurrect an old thread, but how would I add the value labels inside the heatmap cells?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 I would use seaborn's heatmap function, setting `annot=True` when called (http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap)

Comment: @PaulH that's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Someone edited this question to remove the code I used, so I was forced to add it as an answer. Thanks to all who participated in answering this question! I think most of the other answers are better than this code, I'm just leaving this here for reference purposes.

With thanks to [Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h), and [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) (who answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib)), I have some pretty nice-looking output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
column_labels = list('ABCD')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

And here's the output:

[image: Matplotlib HeatMap]