# Moving x-axis to the top of a plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

Based on [this question about heatmaps in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor), I wanted to move the x-axis titles to the top of the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
column_labels = list('ABCD')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top') # <-- This doesn't work!

ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

However, calling [matplotlib's set_label_position](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_label_position) (as notated above) doesn't seem to have the desired effect. Here's my output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Use

```
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
```

to place the tick marks at the top of the image. The command

```
ax.set_xlabel('X LABEL')    
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
```

affects the label, not the tick marks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
column_labels = list('ABCD')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
data = np.random.rand(4, 4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 49):

You want [`set_ticks_position`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_ticks_position) rather than `set_label_position`:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top') # the rest is the same
```

This gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 25):

[tick_params](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) is very useful for setting tick properties. Labels can be moved to the top with:

```
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False,labeltop=True)
```

Comment: Kwargs are booleans so should be `False` and `True` respectively, otherwise works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You've got to do some extra massaging if you want the ticks (not labels) to show up on the top and bottom (not just the top). The only way I could do this is with a minor change to unutbu's code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
column_labels = list('ABCD')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
data = np.random.rand(4, 4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both') # THIS IS THE ONLY CHANGE

ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the person who is searching for top label but starting with `plt` and dont want to switch to `ax` as me, then, start the plot with this two line:

```
    plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
    plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True
```