# How to put both a y-axis label and title on a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

With the following code, it places a label on top of the colorbar, but it also places the y-label on the top as well. I would ideally want one label on top of the colorbar, and one on the right [(as shown here with '# of contacts')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908371/matplotlib-colorbars-and-its-text-labels).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np

number = 100
number_ticks = 9
x_input = np.array([np.linspace(-1.,3.,100),]*number)
y_input = np.array([np.arange(0.,100.,1.),]*number).transpose()
output = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.0,100),]*number)
bounds=np.linspace(0.0,1.0,number_ticks)  
cntr1 = plt.contourf(x_input, y_input, output, vmin = 0.0, vmax = 1.0, levels = bounds)
cbar1 = plt.colorbar()
cbar1.set_label(r"$\bf{title}$", labelpad=-40, y=1.03, rotation=270)  
cbar1.ax.set_ylabel(r"$\bf{y_label}$", labelpad=-40, y=1.03, rotation=0)   
plt.show()
```

The desired output is both a label above the colorbar as well as to the right of it. The above code only places both labels in the same position (i.e. above). The y-label is not going to the side of the colorbar as I would like (as it does in the link I've shared).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`Axes.set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title) method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np

number = 100
number_ticks = 9
x_input = np.array([np.linspace(-1.,3.,100),]*number)
y_input = np.array([np.arange(0.,100.,1.),]*number).transpose()
output = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.0,100),]*number)
bounds=np.linspace(0.0,1.0,number_ticks)  
cntr1 = plt.contourf(x_input, y_input, output, vmin = 0.0, vmax = 1.0, levels = bounds)
cbar1 = plt.colorbar()
cbar1.ax.set_title(r"$\bf{title}$")  
cbar1.ax.set_ylabel(r"$\bf{y_label}$",  labelpad=20, rotation=270)   
plt.show()
```

I think [`ColorbarBase.set_label`](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.set_label) is equivalent to [`cbar1.ax.set_ylabel`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel). And [`Axes.set_label`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_label.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_label) is to specify a legend entry.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOiPI.png)