# How do I set no "ticks" at all in the color bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to set the colorbar with no ticks in any form. I've searched and set the tick parameter at two places. However, still there are some ticks at right boarder.

```
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, spacing='proportional', boundaries=bounds, format='%.1f')

ax2.set_xlabel('t', size=12)
cb.ax.tick_params(size=0)  # these two lines are my searching effort
cb.set_ticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Edit

Here is a self contained code, still has tiny ticks.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(0.05, 6))
tmax=5
tmin=-5
color_num=6
bounds = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, color_num+1)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, color_num)
cmap = plt.cm.tab20
cmaplist = [cmap(i) for i in range(color_num)]
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom map', cmaplist, color_num)
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, spacing='proportional')

cb.ax.tick_params(size=0)  # these two lines are my searching effort
cb.set_ticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a self-contained example, possibly with toy data? Reproducing your snippet (`matplotlib 3.7.3`) results in a colorbar with no ticks, so maybe the issue is not in the lines you posted.

Comment: @Luca I've updated a self-contained code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tiny ticks are generated by `cb.set_ticks([])` when no label is specified (I am using `matplotlib 3.7.3`).

Though it is more a workaround rather than a solution, one could hide the ticks setting the [`Axes.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params). Indeed, one can minimize the ticks and label sizes, and set them to the same color of the figure background, so that they are not visible anymore.

To do so:

```py
cb.ax.tick_params(size=0,                   # tick size
                  labelsize=0,              # label size
                  colors=ax.get_facecolor() # tick and labels color
                  )
```

which results in

[image: colorbar with hidden ticks]

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. What if I want ticks and label to show in the middle of each color block? Is this achievable?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse glad it helped! As for placing the labels inside the colorbar, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908371/matplotlib-colorbars-and-its-text-labels) might help you. If you have any specific issue, I suggest you to open a new question

Answer (score 0):

Create the colorbar with an empty ticklist:

```
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, 
                               ticks = [],  spacing='proportional')
```

[image: segmented colorbar, no ticks]

Comment: Still have tick in `mpl.__version__='3.8.0'`