# Matplotlib subplot y-axis scale overlaps with plot above

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 3 subplots without any white space between them. The default y axis ticklabels use a scale displayed to the top right of the y axis (1e-8 in the example below), which would be fine except for the lower two plots this overlaps with the plot above. Anyone know how to fix this? A small example is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

x = np.arange(0,200)
y = np.random.rand(200) * 10e-8


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,15))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.5, hspace=0.0)
ax0a = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
ax0b = plt.subplot(gs1[1, :])
ax0c = plt.subplot(gs1[2, :])


ax0a.set_xticklabels([])
ax0b.set_xticklabels([]) 

ax0a.plot(x,y)
nbins = len(ax0a.get_xticklabels())
ax0a.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
ax0b.plot(x,y)
ax0b.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
ax0c.plot(x,y)
ax0c.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
```

[image: plot]

so one solution is to use mtick,

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

ax0a.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1e'))
ax0b.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1e'))
ax0c.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1e'))
```

but I would prefer to be able to shift the scale to the left so it is outside the axis if possible.

Comment: Could you divide your data by `10e8`, and just rename the xtick labels to `r'$10^x$'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have two options you might want to look at.

First, set the axis location and size yourself as such:

```
# your imports and data above
fig = plt.figure()
ax0a = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.25])
ax0b = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.39, 0.8, 0.25], sharex=ax0a)
ax0c = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.68, 0.8, 0.25], sharex=ax0a)
ax0a.set_xticklabels([])
ax0b.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax0a.plot(x,y)
nbins = len(ax0a.get_xticklabels())
ax0a.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
ax0b.plot(x,y)
ax0b.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
ax0c.plot(x,y)
ax0c.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

The second option is to manually adjust the location and maybe font size of the offset text:

```
# your original code minus data and imports
fig = plt.figure()
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.5, hspace=0.0)
ax0a = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
ax0b = plt.subplot(gs1[1, :])
ax0c = plt.subplot(gs1[2, :])
ax0a.set_xticklabels([])
ax0b.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax0a.plot(x,y)
nbins = len(ax0a.get_xticklabels())
ax0a.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
ax0b.plot(x,y)
ax0b.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))
ax0c.plot(x,y)
ax0c.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='upper'))

# play around with location and font of offset text here
ax0a.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_x(-0.075)
ax0a.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_size(10)
ax0b.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_x(-0.075)
ax0b.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_size(10)
ax0c.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_x(-0.075)
ax0c.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_size(10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! the second example is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is probably an ugly solution but you could just simply upscale
your data in the lower plots with the range of the power i.e. `ax0b.plot(x, y*1e8)`.
This works for your example at least.

Comment: No I cant do it that way, I need to to keep it in the units it's already in, but thanks for the suggestion.