# change the location of the magnitude ticklabel text in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` in `python3`. The magnitude indicator ('1e7', currently in scientific notation) is now here (on top of boxed axis):

[image]

I would like it to be here (under boxed axis):

[image]

How can I do this? `ticklabel_format` seems to not have any options for changing the location.

Comment: did you check this answer already? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622229/11738630

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. Let's mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positioning the exponent of tick labels when using scientific notation in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620700/positioning-the-exponent-of-tick-labels-when-using-scientific-notation-in-matplo)