# Updating aesthetics of matplotlib heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
column_labels = list('ABCD')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top') # <-- This doesn't work!

ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

Above code is from: [Moving x-axis to the top of a plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

How can I change output from this script so that it looks aesthetically more like this picture:
[image]

Any solution using python matplotlib or seaborn works. I want to insert white between the cells, have the cells be square and also control their size

Comment: You want white spaces between the cells?

Comment: yes and also square cells

Comment: and also I want cell size to be something I can specify

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74688878/3586084) here to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need 2 tricks. First, add the line

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

to make the cells appear as squares (assuming that you have an equal number on the x- and y-axes, as in your example). If you have x squares on the x-axis and y squares on the y-axis, I suspect that you could instead do,

```
ax.set_aspect(float(y) / float(x))
```

Second, you need to add edgecolor to the cells and make the edges thick, so modify your line to e.g.,

```
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, edgecolor='white', linewidths=10)
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: thanks @innisfree, this looks great! However, my dataset might not have the same number of rows and cols.

Comment: Added a comment about that case