# Move tick marks at the top of the seaborn plot

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

I have heatmap in seaborn and i wanted tick marks to be on the top of it

`graph = sns.heatmap(data=df, annot=True , cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})`

I saw answer how to do it on matplotlib ([Moving x-axis to the top of a plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib)) but have no idea how to implement this on seaborn graph

Comment: This is done exactly like in the question you link to. `ax = sns.heatmap(...);
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')`