# How to move labels from bottom to top without adding "ticks"

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, seaborn

How can I position xlabel on top of the plot using something else than "tick_top" - that adds a tick to the x label, and I don't want it.

xlabel on the bottom with no tick: 
[image]

code:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

xlabel on top but with tick: 
[image]

code:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
ax.xaxis.tick_top() # x axis on top
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you do `set_label_position` without `tick_top`?

Comment: I can, but then the xlabels stay on the bottom...

Comment: How about get rid of tick_top and use set_tick_position instead of set_label_position?

Comment: Does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14406214/2988730?

Comment: No it didnt work.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10, labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = False, labeltop=True)
```

the parameter top=False means no ticks. :)

Comment: FYI, it is also applied to ax.tick_params(...)

Answer (score 6):

Ok finally found.

Needs a

```
ax.tick_params(length=0)
```