# How to display width value of "wiggle" stacked graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a [stacked graph](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot.html?highlight=stackplot#matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot)
with matplotlib, and I **want** to use `wiggle` option. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals = [[0, 1, 1, 2, 3],  [0, 0, 2, 4, 4],  [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]]
xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
plt.stackplot(xs, vals, baseline='wiggle')
plt.show()
```

This draws something like this:

[image]

But I want something more (not necessary exactly) like this:

[image]

My problem is, that on `y`-axis there are negative values. This is the result
of using `baseline='wiggle'`, but I need to use `wiggle`, because with `zero`,
the plot is not clear and readable enough.

The `y`-values or *thickness/width* of the whole stackplot is the main reason
why I'm making the graph, so I'd like to show that at the end, the
*thickness/width* of the whole plot is `9`.

What I want:

- to indicate whole stackplot *thickness/width* at several `x`-positions
  (5 should be ok)
- to keep the graph as clean and simple as possible
- solution should be simple (otherwise it's simpler to "draw" numbers on
  finished graph manually)

What I don't want (need):

- negative values on `y`-axis
- I don't need **exactly** the same look as in the picture above, I just need *some* way of indicatin *thickness/width*..

What I tried:

- using `baseline='zero'` - the graph is too confusing, can't use `zero`
- deleting `y`-ticks (`plt.yticks([], [])`) and adding annotations manually -
  this means I have to create annotations every time data changes. And it
  looks just ugly.

Is there any other **simple** way how to display whole stackplot *thickness*/*width*
in a meaningful way?

Also, I'm ok with *"no, there is no simple way of doing this, either you have
to write it yourself or do it manually"* answer.

Comment: Can you do the math on your min/max values for each data point, then pass it into a list of [vlines](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html) as ymin, ymax?

Comment: @G.Anderson - yes I could, I was just trying to find out if there is some easier way than doing it "manually". I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one who doesn't like the negative y-values..

Comment: Also, the "something like this" image I posted is quite ugly - so I was hoping there may be some "cleaner" way too..

Comment: It's a nitpick, but if you wrap it in a function, then it's no longer "manual". When you say manual, I assume you mean going in and adding them one-by-one in each plot. I would say using vlines is "programmatic", but I don't believe there is a _built-in_ way to do what you're asking. You might be able to do something like adding [axis labels at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib). FWIW, I think the second plot you showed is very readable and useful.

Comment: I guess you knew from the start that there is no magic `make_plot_as_I_like_it()` function. So I wonder what this question really asks about. Note that you may of course share a paintbrush picture or similar to convey how you want your graph to look like.

Comment: @G.Anderson: - I meant "manually" as in "I have to write it myself" instead of (hypothetical) built-in `display_stacked_width = on` magical option. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: you're right (see question's last sentence), but I have encountered matplotlib _hacks/cool features_ which were a bit unclear from documentation until I saw them used somewhere. So I was hoping this may have been another such case. Btw - do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: Re: Deleting the question: Personally, I would try to find a solution you're happy with, even if it's more 'manual' than you'd like, and add it as an answer in case someone else down the line has the same question. But if you're going to pursue other plotting options, I'd consider deleting.