# How to rotate Y axis in python

Tags: python, plot

Hi I attach picture what i want to do in python

[image]

and this is my code:

```
def HeatMapFunction(username,roundNumber,dominateFlag):
#  Connect to DB and create a Board
if(dominateFlag==0):
  print("REGULAR BOARD HAS BEEN SELECTED TO BE CREATED")
  listOfCardByRound = db.GetBoard(username, int(roundNumber))
  CreateCardBoard(listOfCardByRound)
if (dominateFlag == 1):
  print("DOMINATE BOARD HAS BEEN  SELECTED TO BE CREATED")
  listOfCardByRound = db.DominatValue(username, int(roundNumber))
  CreateDominantCardBoard(listOfCardByRound)
PDF2Image()
listOfCoodinate = db.GetCoordinateByRoundNumber(username, int(roundNumber))
xCor = []
yCor = []
#  Convert String point to float point
for x in listOfCoodinate[0]:
    xCor.append(float(x))
for y in listOfCoodinate[1]:
    yCor.append(float(y))
plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
#  Calibrate the camera y axis for the image
map_img = mpimg.imread('out.jpg')
hmax = sns.kdeplot(xCor, yCor, cmap="Blues", shade=False)
hmax.collections[0].set_alpha(0)
plt.imshow(map_img, zorder=0, extent=[0, 2006, 0, 960], aspect='auto')
#  Export File to PDF
plt2PDF(plt)
webbrowser.open_new(r'testPlot.pdf')
plt.show()
```

There is a code that ive done and all i want to do is just rotate the y axis

Comment: [Why not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: 1) Please post actual code and not an image 2)whats wrong with the code you have

Comment: Thanks , edited!

Comment: It may not be, but is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib) what you're looking for?