# Move ticks and labels to the top of a pyplot figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406214/moving-x-axis-to-the-top-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib), moving the xticks and labels of an `AxesSubplot` object can be done with `ax.xaxis.tick_top()`. However, I cannot get this to work with multiple axes inside a figure.

Essentially, I want to move the xticks to the very top of the figure (only displayed at the top for the subplots in the first row).

Here's a silly example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig.set_figheight(5)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
for ax in axs.flatten():
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()
plt.show()
```

Which shows

[image: Close try]

My desired result is this same figure but with the `xticks` and `xticklabels` at the top of the two plots in the first row.

Comment: I think `sharex` is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @BigBen for the `sharex` comment. It is indeed what's preventing `tick_top` to work.

To get your results, you can combine using `tick_top` for the two top plots and use `tick_params` for the bottom two:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=False) # Do not share xaxis
for ax in axs.flatten()[0:2]:
  ax.xaxis.tick_top()
for ax in axs.flatten()[2:]:
  ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',labelbottom=False)
```

See a live implementation [here](https://1000words-hq.com/n/zRGDjshUglK).