# Can python make a tile plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Can python (eg matplotlib) make a tile plot like the following, where color indicates the intensity at each data point? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke your url is mangled, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor

Comment: @tcaswell can't edit it -- so I deleted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example taken from http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html:

[image]

```
"""
Show how to modify the coordinate formatter to report the image "z"
value of the nearest pixel given x and y
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')

numrows, numcols = X.shape
def format_coord(x, y):
    col = int(x+0.5)
    row = int(y+0.5)
    if col>=0 and col<numcols and row>=0 and row<numrows:
        z = X[row,col]
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f, z=%1.4f'%(x, y, z)
    else:
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f'%(x, y)

ax.format_coord = format_coord
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

You only need all of that machinery if you want the mouse to report back the value of the data under your mouse.  To generate the image all you really need is  [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

```
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
```

You can control the color mapping via the `cmap` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`image_zcode`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html) The example given is:

```
"""
Show how to modify the coordinate formatter to report the image "z"
value of the nearest pixel given x and y
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')

numrows, numcols = X.shape
def format_coord(x, y):
    col = int(x+0.5)
    row = int(y+0.5)
    if col>=0 and col<numcols and row>=0 and row<numrows:
        z = X[row,col]
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f, z=%1.4f'%(x, y, z)
    else:
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f'%(x, y)

ax.format_coord = format_coord
plt.show()
```