# Need a confirmation of a library bug

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I am quite new with Python and even I have done pretty deep and long research I think I need a confirmation from community before opening a case on github.

I am plotting two ["hinton plots"](http://matplotlib.org/examples/specialty_plots/hinton_demo.html) but I am using color range to represent matrix value. 
 **Using subplot for some reason draws background of *first plot in last subplot* with first `mymap` color** (blue in my case). If overwrites `set_facecolor = 'gray'` in any case (even if I am setting background color after plotting). Also I found that this bug accrues only if `matrix` values are greater than 0. 
 Please see pictures (and image descriptions) and code below.

*Background of the first picture on the second subplot is blue.*
[image: Background of the first picture on the second subplot is blue]
*Third subplot added with no data, now it is blue colored and first square of second subplot is not.*
[image: Third subplot added with no data, now it is blue colored and first square of second subplot is not]

For first picture result change 6-th line to: `fig, (axe_1, axe_2) = plt.subplots(1,2)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


fig, (axe_1, axe_2, axe_3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)
my_min, my_max = (0, 10)
step = 1
mymap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my list", ['blue','red'])
levels = range(my_min, my_max+step, step)
matrix = [None, None]
matrix[0] = np.asanyarray([[0, 1, 2], [3, 0, 5], [6, 7, 0]])
matrix[1] = np.asanyarray([[0, 9, 8], [7, 0, 6], [5, 4, 0]])

for iter, item in enumerate([axe_1, axe_2]):

    item.patch.set_facecolor('gray')
    item.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
    item.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    item.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    Z = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    CS3 = plt.contourf(Z, levels, cmap=mymap)
    for (x, y), z in np.ndenumerate(matrix[iter]):
        b = (float(z)-my_min)/(my_max-my_min)
        g = 0
        r = 1-b
        rect = plt.Rectangle([y, x], 0.9, 0.9, facecolor=(r, g, b), edgecolor="black")
        item.add_patch(rect)
    item.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

If I haven't made any stupid mistakes and you will confirm this is a bug I will open an issue on github.

Comment: Could you make clearer what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Updated question, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the call to `plt.contourf` (which I do not strictly understand why is there).  But, it is being called through the state machine interface and hence both times through the loop plots to `axe_2` (as that is what `plt.gca()` returns).  You are plotting the contour of a 2x2 all 0 array, which it (correctly) draws as a blue box at [0, 0, 1, 1], which is the blue edge you see.

It works 'correctly' in the case of 3 axes as `pyplot` thinks the last axes is the current axes.

Comment: I reduced my code to this minimal example for you not to read tons of unrelated code, but in my original project I use `plt.contourf` to generate mappable for `mpl.colorbar()` to see the color level difference.
As I understand this is not a bug isn't it?

Comment: no, this is not a bug, the library is correctly doing what you told it to do in the way it claimed it would do it ;)  Instead of drawing the rectangles by hand your self, use `pcolor` and make the edges thick (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor)

Comment: Yeah, reading what you are doing more carefully (that is for meaning, not correctness), you are re-inventing several wheels.  `pcolor` will do both the color mapping and the rectangle drawing for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look forward to use this tool!