# How to control the cell size of a pyplot pcolor heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a pair of lists of numbers representing points in a 2-D space, and I want to represent the y/x ratios for these points as a 1-dimensional heatmap, with a diverging color map centered around 1, or the logs of my ratios, with a diverging color map centered around 0.

How do I do that?

My current attempt (borrowing somewhat from [Heatmap in matplotlib with pcolor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor)):

```
from matplotlib import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# There must be a better way to generate arrays of random values
x_values = [np.random.random() for _ in range(10)]
y_values = [np.random.random() for _ in range(10)]
labels = list("abcdefghij")
ratios = np.asarray(y_values) / np.asarray(x_values)
axis = plt.gca()
# I transpose the array to get the points arranged vertically
heatmap = axis.pcolor(np.log2([ratios]).T, cmap=plt.cm.PuOr)
# Put labels left of the colour cells
axis.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)) + 0.5, minor=False)
# (Not sure I get the label order correct...)
axis.set_yticklabels(labels)
# I don't want ticks on the x-axis: this has no meaning here
axis.set_xticks([])
plt.show()
```

Some points I'm not satisfied with:

- The coloured cells I obtain are horizontally-elongated rectangles. I would like to control the width of these cells and obtain a column of cells.
- I would like to add a legend for the color map. `heatmap.colorbar = plt.colorbar()` fails with `RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`

One important point:

- matplotlib/pyplot always leaves me confused: there seems to be a lot of ways to do things and I get lost in the documentation. I never know what would be the "clean" way to do what I want: I welcome suggestions of reading material that would help me clarify my very approximative understanding of these things.

Comment: I felt the same way when I first started using matplotlib. I found looking at  [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/) very helpful. Also, I know that you didn't ask this in your question, but to answer the question in the comment in your code, yes, there's a simpler way: np.random.random() takes a size argument and can return an array of random numbers: `x_values, y_values = np.random.random((2, 10))`

Answer (score 3):

Just 2 more lines:

```
axis.set_aspect('equal') # X scale matches Y scale
plt.colorbar(mappable=heatmap) # Tells plt where it should find the color info.
```

Can't answer your final question very well. Part of it is due to we have two branches of doing things in `matplotlib`: the axis way (`axis.do_something`...) and the `MATLAB` clone way `plt.some_plot_method`.  Unfortunately we can't change that, and it is a good feature for people to migrate into `matplotlib`.  As far as the "Clean way" is concerned, I prefer to use whatever produces the shorter code.  I guess that is inline with `Python` motto: *Simple is better than complex* and *Readability counts*.

[image]

Comment: In my test code, the `axis.set_aspect('equal')` worked. But in my real code, I had a `plt.axis("tight")` that seemed to force the cells to fill the available width on the figure. When I remove it, I obtain a thin column of coloured cells, but the column is topped by extra white cells, and there is a lot of white space at the left of the figure.

Comment: `axis.set_ylim((0, len(labels)))` solves the problem of the white cells topping the column. I still can't find how to get the figure not to have a lot of blank space on the left.

Comment: Using `bbox_inches='tight'`in the `savefig` options instead of `plt.axis("tight")` solves the other problem.